# Sort function on a date range to transpose in ascending order

Tags: sorting, datetime, google-sheets, transpose

I have a column with thousands of dates in it. I'd like a row of each unique date sorted in ascending order. This column has been named `create_date`. So:

```
=transpose(unique(create_date))
```

produces results that looks like this:

```
6/1/2012   5/1/2008    7/1/2008    3/1/2010    1/1/2011    6/1/2011
```

But I wanted the range sorted in ascending order from left to right. So I tried nesting my formula in a sort function like this:

```
=sort(transpose(unique(create_date)),1,TRUE)
```

I've never used `sort` before. The function didn't produce an error, but didn't actually change anything, the results are as they were before being wrapped ins sort.

Using formula (I could easily do this manually), how would I sort a column of dates to read from left to right in ascending order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=unique(transpose(sort(create_date,1,true)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to tweak @pnuts answer a little. This appears to work:

```
=transpose(sort(unique(create_date),1,true))
```

Comment: Thing is on the spreadsheet I have the original answer did not actually work. It did not return an error though. I'm using "The new Gsheets" if that makes a difference.

Comment: INteresting. I just checked in on another sheet on another date range. Both formulas work :-/
But not on this original doc!
I'll leave both answers up incase anyone comes across a similar issue